# How to prove equality lebesgue integral of a function over two sets, given the measure of a certain composition of functions?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let E and F be measurable sets such that m(E△F) = 0 (where E△F = (E − F) ∪ (F − E)). If f
is a measurable function on E∪F such that it is integrable on E, then show that (∫ over F) of f=
(∫ over E) of f.

Now, since f is integrable over E∪F, it is obviously integrable over E△F. But how can I show that the integral equals for individual sets?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $m(E \Delta F) = \int |1_E - 1_F|\,dm$. So the claim follows from basic properties of the integral.